How to record api in jmeter from browser stack application
I have to record the jmeter script for mobile application. if the mobile application installed on browser stack , then is it possible to record api of application from browser stack using jmeter.
How to record application api's on jmeter using browserstack?

Looking into BrowserStack documentation it should be possible to configure a proxy server, for HTTP protocol it will be sufficient.
However for HTTPS you will need to perform some extra configuration, in particular to install JMeter certificate onto mobile device and then:

for iOS you will need to enable full trust for the certificate
for Android you will need to amend your application network security like it's described in Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording

So it might be a better idea to use a real device for recording. If you don't have a real device you can always use an emulator or a simulator, both are free

Hi Ivan,
Thanks for your response. Then how to set proxy and configuration for simulator?
